# flash cs5.5 as3 autocomplete dont work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, autocomplete, flash-cs5.5

I.m using flash cs5.5 for programing as3 flash games
recently i heard that cs5.5 support autocomplete feature and i even found how to toggle it on
at (tools->show code hint) 
but nothing seems to work
does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening the IDE? I've found in CS5.5, about once a week I get a bug where hinting just stops working entirely. Closing and reopening the IDE fixes it every time for me.

Comment: its never worked.. i opened the ide many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the Flash CS5.5 autocomplete spotty at best.  It seems to only work when:

1. Editing ActionScript on a keyframe when the classes are imported earlier on the frame and/or in the default namespace
2. You are editing an AS3 class file that is a linkage to a MovieClip or document in an FLA file that is also open

Seconded, FlashDevelop is indeed a great IDE, but Windows only.  I recently switched to FlashBuilder (using a Mac now).  Both have robust autocomplete functionality and are much better suited to writing applications than Flash.

Comment: i switched to FleshDevelop following the recommendation of the first answer.  for now the auto-complete is flawless but i had some pain adjusting my code to the new environment. thanks anyway. (and i use windows anyway so no problem there)

Answer (score 1):

Use flashdevelop ( you can download from here - http://www.flashdevelop.org/ it is free ). This is the best as3 editor ever made. Writing a scripts in Adobe flash is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in CS6 and after creating several classes and linking Away3d. After several restarts, nothing worked. I went into the Preferences > ActionScript and set my cache size from the default 800 files up to 5000 files. I restarted again and now it works. Hopefully this will help anyone using Flash CS#.

Answer (score 0):

On the actions panel click on the dropdown on the top left corner and check "script assist"

Comment: Per the FAQ, please do not add signatures at the end of your answers.